# Can someone explain this equation?

Tags: cryptography

Okay, here is the exact phrasing:

We want to get two values $A$ and $B$, where we test many values of $A$ to get the smallest value of $B$. 
$B$ is the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in the result of: $(1 + x)^A \pmod{p, x^{38} - 5}$.
$p = 2975390752039679348694694675193$, a prime number. $x^{38} - 5$ is an irreducible polynomial in the field $F_p[x]$.

The range of allowable values of $A$ and $B$ are:
$1 \le A \le p^{38} - 1$ and
$0 <= B < p$

Comment: It's not an equation. An equation has an equals sign (equating two sides, hence the name.) and $\pmod {U,V}$ is a little confusing.

Comment: What context did you see this in @badosky?  If we see the paper maybe we can figure it out.

Comment: I've rephrased the question

Comment: As phrased, just take $A$ to be any number between $1$ and $14$ - then $B=0$....